# Nifi merge content by similar attribute value

Tags: apache-nifi

I have zip files like bellow in the directory:

```
139909-JSON.zip
139910-JSON.zip
...
```

And the content of each zip file is like this:

```
1
  672748
    1399101-672748-content.json
    1399101-672748-header.json
2
  684919
    1399101-684919-content.json
    1399101-684919-header.json
...
```

Im using the `GetFile > UnpackContent > UpdateAttribute -> MergeContent` flow right now. But I cant merge truly my data.

**GetFile:** get all zip files.

**UnpackContent:** unpack zip files and get all `.json` files.

**UpdateAttribute:** I have `672748` and `684919` from `filename` in the `TracingNo` variable.

I need to merge every file with the same `TracingNo` value together in one JSON file.

How can I do this?

Comment: Do you know how many files for each tracing-no ? How merged file should look like? What have you tried so far?

Comment: @daggett Minimum 1 and maximum 2 files for each `TracingNo`. The content of each file is JSON object, and I want to merge the theme in a new file in JSON array. example `[{file_1}, {file_2}]`.

Comment: @daggett I Merged every 2 files together. but I can't merge them with equal `TracingNo`.

Comment: Why you can't merge them with equal TracingNo?

Comment: @daggett I don't know. they can't merge with theme truly by `TracingNo`. have you any useful example or resource about that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem in this statement: Minimum 1 and maximum 2 files for each TracingNo.

It'll be better to know number of files to make merge content

However try to do it in 2 steps:

MergeContent with parameters:

```
Merge Strategy =    Bin-Packing Algorithm
Merge Format =  Binary Concatenation
Correlation Attribute Name = TracingNo
Minimum Number of Entries = 2
Maximum Number of Entries = 2
Max Bin Age = 10 seconds
Delimiter Strategy = Text
Header = [
Footer = ]
Demarcator = ,
```

This processor will wait for a second file during 10 sec. The single files will be classified as failed and you could use ReplaceText to add `[]` into them.

Answer (score 1):

What if you used a RouteAttribute to have all flowfiles with the same TracingNo routed the same way to have it route to the same MergeContent.
This can be done to RouteAttribute so that each TracingNo get sent their own way, so that all flowfiles in each direction have the same TracingNo to allow for you to handle the same values and combine them

Comment: It's a good idea when I have a few `TracingNo`, but there are too many.

Comment: You could use several RouteAttributes to route the data over several processors.